# GoogleMap. Markers icon image dissapear and/or overlap them

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Since last monday we have problem in google maps. First of all, we use custom markers to show the results of a search "grouped" by concept, that's mean than we show a yellow box with a text and a number with its count. If you take a look at this image you will see the errors

(Link to the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCXpG.jpg )

- In "Grierkenland (556)" or "Turkije (392)" markers there aren't any kind of image there (behold the red boxes)
- In "Cyrpus (43)" you will see the image than i put in each marker but only on this marker appears. Appears too FOUR more images overlaped one each other (numbers 1 to 4 on the screenshot, the original image is the number 1, the rest is the same image overlap on each other)

We don't change anything for a month and, i said before, from this monday the marker's image doesnt work at all. Our code are:

Create the icon. Generates an object with the image's url (the pathPrefix is a string with some like "www.test.com", for ex.):

```
 getLocIcon: function (markerLength) {
        var markerSize = 100; 
        if (markerLength > 18) {
            markerSize = 183;
        } else if (markerLength > 15) {
            markerSize = 146;
        } else if (markerLength > 13) {
            markerSize = 122;
        }

        icon =
            {
                url: priv.pathPrefix + '/images/googlemaps/loc-marker-' + markerSize + '.png',
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 0),
                size: new google.maps.Size(markerSize, 22)
            };

        return icon;
    },
```

Create the marker.  Generates a marker object with all the information required, including the "icon" object:

```
createLinkMarker: function (gllPosition, strTargetText, strTargetLink, strMarkerToolTip) {
        var locationMarkerText = "<nobr>" + strMarkerToolTip + " (" + strTargetText + ")</nobr>";
        var otherOpts =
            {
                position: gllPosition,
                map: priv.googleMap,
                labelClass: "locationLabel",
                icon: priv.getLocIcon((strMarkerToolTip + " (" + strTargetText + ")").length),
                clickable: true,
                draggable: false,
                labelContent: locationMarkerText,
                //anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(15, 0),
                title: strMarkerToolTip
            };
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel(otherOpts);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            location.href = strTargetLink;
        });

        return marker;
    },
```

The rest of the code to include the markers inside google maps (priv.googleMap is the google map's object and markers are an array of marker getted from createLinkMarker function):

```
var markerMgrOptions = { maxZoom: priv.maxZoom, trackMarkers: false };
priv.markerManager = new MarkerManager(priv.googleMap, markerMgrOptions);
[ ... ]
priv.markerManager.clearMarkers();
priv.markerManager.addMarkers(markers, priv.minZoom, priv.maxZoom);
priv.markerManager.refresh();
```

Do you know if there are something new or a bad practice there?

Thanks in advance and regards.

Comment: Try with the previous version of Google Maps API with adding `v=3.14` parameter to your API call. I had a similar problem on different plugin for google maps; it had started to work unexpectedly. Then I saw that on the new version of the API, something was wrong with the plugin, then I checked and found a newer version of the plugin and my problem is solved.

Comment: You're my hero, works perfectly!